# How to add text to a raphael js element

Tags: javascript, text, raphael

I want to add text to a element in raphael js,
I have added text with

```
r.text(30, 20, "ellipse").attr({fill: color});
```

But how to add this text to

```
ec = r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20);
```

regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Raphael does not have child/parent relationship between elements, so you will set same position for them e.g.

```
ec = paper.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20);
paper.text(190, 100, "ellipse").attr({fill: '#ff0000'});
```

So if you want a ellipse with text, create your own JavaScript object which handles positioning of both.

or alternate way is to group elements via `set` e.g.

```
var eltext = paper.set();
el = paper.ellipse(0, 0, 30, 20);
text = paper.text(0, 0, "ellipse").attr({fill: '#ff0000'})
eltext.push(el);
eltext.push(text);
eltext.translate(100,100)
```

Comment: @pahnin, it can be done but nor the exact way you want, you can group them via a set

Answer (score 2):

You can easly add text to youR elements creating a text Raphael element and add as attribute **text** into your element.

```
 elText = r.text(.....);
 yourEl.attr({text:elText});
```