# Javascript hover function to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I know how to make a box appear when you hover over a circle, however it is a big one and it will ruin the experience in my opinion. It is an alert. I would prefer it so that it is a smaller box, which just appears over the circle when you hover and not a huge one, if you get what I mean. However I am not sure how to make this happen. Any help will be great

## **Knockout JS 2.0.0**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);
  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  backGround.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });
  var face = paper.circle(200, 200, 100);
  face.attr({
    fill: "Red"
  });
  face.hover(hoverHandler);
};

function hoverHandler() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

So again when the user hovers over the red circle i want a small box to appear over it and say hi there

Thanks

**Edit** : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEaFx/72/)

Comment: where is the html/css?

Comment: Where's the code for the `Raphael` function? What libraries are you using to achieve what you have so far?

Comment: @Nevershow2016 What is the meaning behind the Knockout JS 2.0 Library heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is that you want, you should call the function (e.g., anonymous) and **pass to it your bar** to modify its properties. Then, on mouse `hover` the bar appears over the circle.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);
  var face = paper.circle(200, 200, 100);
  face.attr({
    fill: "Red"
  });
  var backGround = paper.rect(150, 150, 100, 100);
  backGround.attr({
    fill: "",
    "stroke-width": 0
  });
  face.hover(function(){hoverHandler(backGround)});
};

function hoverHandler(l) {
  alert("hi");
  l.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkL0ug3h/

Answer (score 0):

You may have to fiddle with where you want to position your elements but this should get you going in the right direction. The main issue your were probably going to face was that your call back was outside the on load function call so if you were to try and pass your paper object to your call back function it would have returned undefined.

Here is another good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140228/how-to-add-text-to-a-raphael-js-element) on adding text using Raphael.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/LGKxeR

**Raphael/JavaScript Code:**

```
     window.onload = function() {

  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);

  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  backGround.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });
  var face = paper.circle(200, 200, 100);
  face.attr({
    fill: "Red"
  });

  face.hover(hoverHandler);


  //Moved this inside of the onload event
  function hoverHandler() {

    //create the alert
    var alert = paper.rect(175, 175, 50, 50);

    alert.attr({

      fill: "blue"

    });

    //add the text

    var text = paper.text(200, 200, "Hi!");

    //add some attributes
    text.attr({
      "font-size": 22,
      "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    });

  }

};
```